# Inside an object is it possible for a method to use the return value of another method?

Tags: javascript, methods, javascript-objects

In the test code below a factory function creates an object.  Inside the new object are 2 methods, `totalCost` & `withShipping`.  Is there a pattern I can use that will allow `withShipping` to use the return value of `totalCost`?  As configured it throws an error.  Thanks so much for any help!

```js
"use strict"

function factoryTest(x) {
    let returnTest = {
        numberOfEngines: x.numberOfEngines,
        costPerEngine: x.costPerEngine,
        totalCost: function() {
            return x.numberOfEngines * x.costPerEngine;
        },
        withShipping: function() {
            return x.totalCost() * 2;
        }

    }
    return returnTest;
}

let aircraft = factoryTest({numberOfEngines: 2, costPerEngine: 40000});

console.log(aircraft.totalCost());
console.log(aircraft.withShipping());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use `this` to access the current instantiation:

```js
"use strict"

function factoryTest(x) {
    let returnTest = {
        numberOfEngines: x.numberOfEngines,
        costPerEngine: x.costPerEngine,
        totalCost: function() {
            return x.numberOfEngines * x.costPerEngine;
        },
        withShipping: function() {
            return this.totalCost() * 2;
        }

    }
    return returnTest;
}

let aircraft = factoryTest({numberOfEngines: 2, costPerEngine: 40000});

console.log(aircraft.totalCost());
console.log(aircraft.withShipping());
```

Another workable method, since you're using the factory function pattern, would be to define the `totalCost` function and everything else *outside* of `returnTest` and then call it:

```js
"use strict"

function factoryTest({
  numberOfEngines,
  costPerEngine
}) {
  const totalCost = () => numberOfEngines * costPerEngine;
  return {
    numberOfEngines,
    costPerEngine,
    totalCost,
    withShipping: () => totalCost() * 2,
  };
}

const aircraft = factoryTest({
  numberOfEngines: 2,
  costPerEngine: 40000
});

console.log(aircraft.totalCost());
console.log(aircraft.withShipping());
```

Comment: You're right!  One question doesn't `x` and `this` reference the same object?  Why does `this` work and `x` fails?  They seem so similar.

Comment: `x` actually refers to the object `{numberOfEngines: 2, costPerEngine: 40000}` notice how it doesn't have "totalCost" defined on it? All `x` has are "numberOfEngines" and "costPerEngine"